# Bootstrap "tabs" and "navbar" is not working in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, bootstrap-4, electron

I am Loading bootstrap by

```
    <script>
      let $ = require('jquery') ;
    </script>
    <script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       require('./renderer.js')
     </script>
```

but my navbar is not working

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery library should be initialized like that for bootstrap to work :

```
<script>
  window.jQuery = require('jquery')
</script>
```